# Magento 2.2.5 Emails are not receiving

Tags: email, magento-2.2.5

I am using Magento 2.2.5. Order confirmation emails, Invoice emails and any of the custom emails are not receiving to the particular domain based email. Client has the server on go daddy VPS. Mails are receiving for the gmail and only domain based emails has this issue.

Comment: can you receive emails that are not from magento?

Comment: Yes, Other than Magento emails are sending/receiving fine.

Comment: check spam and promotion folder also

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check cronjobs are enabled in the server. you can check this by using command crontab -l. If no crons are configured do the following.

**create the Magento crontab:**

1. Log in as, or switch to, the Magento file system owner.
2. Change to your Magento installation directory.
3. Enter the following command:

> php bin/magento cron:install [--force]

For more information https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Comment: I have configured cron jobs and it is working fine without issues.

Comment: Did you try smtp?